# Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')" while building a simple tic tac toe game using react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create an array to store value of square each time I click. Then I can use that array to implement logic of the game. But each time I click on the square it rerender and show blank page with error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [turn, setTurn] = useState(false);
    const [square, setSquare] = useState(Array(9).fill({value: null, isClick: false}))

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Turn: {turn ? "O" : "X"}</h1>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square turn={turn} setTurn={setTurn} square={square[0]} setSquare={setSquare} />
        <Square turn={turn} setTurn={setTurn} square={square[1]} setSquare={setSquare} />
        <Square turn={turn} setTurn={setTurn} square={square[2]} setSquare={setSquare} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square turn={turn} setTurn={setTurn} square={square[3]} setSquare={setSquare} />
        <Square turn={turn} setTurn={setTurn} square={square[4]} setSquare={setSquare} />
        <Square turn={turn} setTurn={setTurn} square={square[5]} setSquare={setSquare} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square turn={turn} setTurn={setTurn} square={square[6]} setSquare={setSquare} />
        <Square turn={turn} setTurn={setTurn} square={square[7]} setSquare={setSquare} />
        <Square turn={turn} setTurn={setTurn} square={square[8]} setSquare={setSquare} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

const Square = ({ turn, setTurn, square, setSquare }) => {
    
  const clickHandle = () => {
    if (!square.isClick) {
      setSquare({value: turn ? "O" : "X", isClick: true})
      setTurn(!turn);
    }
};

  return (
    <div>
      <button className="square" onClick={clickHandle}>
        {square.value}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried to console.log to debug but somehow the `square` state is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting state then you are setting it as a single object which is wrong because you are initially taking an array, so it should be an array of object and you only have to udpate that particular object on which you have clicked.

[`CODESANDBOX`](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-leaf-sq6tl3?file=/src/App.js)

```
const clickHandle = () => {
    if (!square.isClick) {
      setSquare((oldValues) => {
        return oldValues.map((o, i) => {
          return i === index
            ? {
                ...o,
                value: turn ? "O" : "X",
                isClick: true
              }
            : o;
        });
      });
      setTurn(!turn);
    }
```

Comment: I thought that I passed `square` props with `square[i]` so it would be single object, wouldn't it? Btw, it works, thank you!